# How to do GUI stuff in background? (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-gui

I tried to do gui stuff with `asynctask`, but it not works on every device. Why?

Here is my code:

```
public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<ReadEvent, Void, String> {

    long difference;
    ReadEvent readevent;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(ReadEvent... readevents) {
        this.difference = (readevents[0].getDtstart() - calendar_millis) / 1000 / 24 / 60 / 60;
        this.readevent = readevents[0];

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        MonthFragment.this.addDate((int) difference + MonthFragment.this.start - 1, readevent.getEventname(), readevent.getCalendarid(), readevent.getEventcolor());
    }
}
```

This is within a `fragment`. The method addDate adds the `TextView` to GUI. It works great on Honor Huawei 6X Honor (Android 7.0) it works great. On BQ Aquaris X5 (Android 7.1.1) it doesn't.

What is the best way, to do GUI stuff in background?

Comment: you cannot do (G)UI stuff in the background, and you aren't doing it with that code either. onPostExecute runs on the UI thread

Comment: @TimCastelijns the method OP is talking about is called from onPostExecute so it is not in background.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "it doesn't" means. When you used your debugger, or logging statements, to see what is going on, what did you learn? And why are you using an `AsyncTask` here in the first place? There is no disk I/O or network I/O going on.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I've got a viewpager. When I scroll it should load data not until fragment is loaded.

Comment: That does not explain why you are using an `AsyncTask` here.

Comment: You're introducing a memory leak to both you Fragment and it's owning Activity, because you're AsyncTask appears to be an Inner class that gets an implicit reference to its containing class i.e MonthFragment, if you rotate and don't stop AsyncTask, mem leak occurs silently. What I recommend doing sending a broadcast event to BroadcastReceiver registered in your fragment and safely updating your UI code from there, just remember to unregister you BroadcastReceiver in onPause/onStop and register in the reciprocal method, e.g. onStart/onResume.

Answer (score -1):

AsyncTask is rather inconsistent between platforms. Try this in `onPostExecute`:

```
if (getView() != null)
    getView().post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            MonthFragment.this.addDate((int) difference + MonthFragment.this.start - 1, readevent.getEventname(), readevent.getCalendarid(), readevent.getEventcolor());
        }
    });
```

But I'd rather use thread pools, they offer much more control.

Comment: *AsyncTask is rather inconsistent between platforms.* you got some source to back up that statement?

Comment: nope, just general experience while I was testing it on several devices in 2.2 era. this data may be outdated, and I might be wrong, but I am really afraid of AsyncTasks since then)

Comment: @ubik This implementation can cause an easy memory leak.

Comment: @WadeWilson come on, he's already got ref to his fragment in AsyncTask. this is not much worse, especially in case of short task like this.

Comment: @cab404, just because he already has a reference doesn't mean it's correct. This won't cause a memory leak if he makes sure to cancel the task  when the Fragment is stopping, if not, and the Fragment gets destroyed, he will leak memory. It's the same issue when creating an anonymous Handler in an Activity/Fragment. I'm just informing him because it's an easy to introduce bug that can be annoying to track down later. Especially if he reuses this pattern throughout his app.

Comment: @WadeWilson well, if he cancels task and drop refs to it, it will go with any refs to runnable too. basically this runnable is just one more link in hanging ref tree, which would be destroyed on first gc sweep .-.

Comment: @cab404 I don't wanna get into an argument over this, I was just informing. Your ex. still can cause a leak.That Runnable will get an implicity reference to the Fragment, which then gets added to a Handler that may out live the Fragment if the device is ever rotated. It's a very unlikely condition of occurring, but still possible. If the devices rotates, and the OS tries to gc the Activity and Fragment, it can't because it there's an inaccessible reference to it. View.post() attaches the Runnables to a Handler that is on the Main thread, out lasting activities/fragments.